# How to disable VM from accidental startup in vSphere?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

This is vCenter 5.1 and I would like to disable startup of a certain Virtual Machine.

There are several reasons why I would like that (the machine eats too many resources, or is infected, or triggers a license).

I don't want to remove the VM from the Inventory.

I have tried reducing RAM to the minimum (4MB) and kind of works (the OS crashes when trying to boot), but I wish there was a cleaner method.

Answer (score 6):

One solution would be to convert the VM to a template - then it can't start, it's quick too and very easy to reverse.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a virtual machine to be used for *any* reason, you can remove it from the inventory. It can be re-added, but this eliminates the chance of an inadvertent power-on.

If you want to isolate a virtual machine for security reasons (*e.g. network compromise*), disconnect its network adapter.

If you have a licensing issue, that may also be handled by a disconnected network adapter, depending on the licensing method.

If there is a chance that another user would power the VM on, set more granular permissions in your vSphere infrastructure and restrict access to the VM in question.

Comment: I like the permissions idea. I'm basically a vCenter administrator, so I created a new role which identical to Administrator except it doesn't have "VM->Interaction->Power On" priviledge enabled, and assigned it to me on those VMs.

Comment: @LatinSuD I'd recommend converting to template (*mark as template*) or removing the VM from inventory.

Answer (score 1):

Export the VM and delete it from the inventory (no other way). When you want to use it, import it back.